# VB.net non MVC RAZOR | Need help, javascript stack procress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a shopping website and have 2 menu, when i call page from ajax to show on my content zone (On DIV).

```
<script>
   $(function () {
        $("#chicken_tab2").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/view/Content/Index_cp.vbhtml",
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                $("#getcontent").html(data);

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

My content come to show but it can't use javascipt from _Layout.vbtml.
Then i put Main.js(it's Cart jquery)

```
<script src="~/view/Cart/main.js"></script>
```

inside main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
//var getnum = $('#getnum').val();
//alert(getnum);

var cartWrapper = $('.cd-cart-container');
//product id - you don't need a counter in your real project but you can use your real product id
var productId = 0;

if( cartWrapper.length > 0 ) {
    //store jQuery objects
    var cartBody = cartWrapper.find('.body')
    var cartList = cartBody.find('ul').eq(0);
    var cartTotal = cartWrapper.find('.checkout').find('span');
    var cartTrigger = cartWrapper.children('.cd-cart-trigger');
    var cartCount = cartTrigger.children('.count')
    var addToCartBtn = $('.cd-add-to-cart');
    var undo = cartWrapper.find('.undo');
    var undoTimeoutId;
    var getnum = $('.getnum');


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //O function Strat





    //O function End




    //add product to cart
    addToCartBtn.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        addToCart($(this));




    });

    //open/close cart
    cartTrigger.on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        toggleCart();
    });

    //close cart when clicking on the .cd-cart-container::before (bg layer)
    cartWrapper.on('click', function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is($(this)) ) toggleCart(true);
    });

    //delete an item from the cart
    cartList.on('click', '.delete-item', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        removeProduct($(event.target).parents('.product'));
    });

    //update item quantity
    cartList.on('change', 'select', function(event){
        quickUpdateCart();
    });

    //reinsert item deleted from the cart
    //undo.on('click', 'a', function(event){
    //  clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
    //  event.preventDefault();
    //  cartList.find('.deleted').addClass('undo-deleted').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
    //      $(this).off('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend').removeClass('deleted undo-deleted').removeAttr('style');
    //      quickUpdateCart();
    //  });
    //  undo.removeClass('visible');
    //});
}

function toggleCart(bool) {

    var cartIsOpen = ( typeof bool === 'undefined' ) ? cartWrapper.hasClass('cart-open') : bool;

    if( cartIsOpen ) {
        cartWrapper.removeClass('cart-open');
        //reset undo
        clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
        undo.removeClass('visible');
        cartList.find('.deleted').remove();

        setTimeout(function(){
            cartBody.scrollTop(0);
            //check if cart empty to hide it
            if( Number(cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text()) === 0) cartWrapper.addClass('empty');
        }, 500);
    } else {
        cartWrapper.addClass('cart-open');
    }
}

function addToCart(trigger) {
    var ids = trigger.data('ids');
    var item = trigger.data('item');
    var cartIsEmpty = cartWrapper.hasClass('empty');
    //update cart product list ****add trigger in ()
    addProduct(trigger.data('item'),trigger.data('detail'), trigger.data('productname'), trigger.data('pic'), $('#' + ids + '').val());
    //update number of items
    updateCartCount(cartIsEmpty);
    //update total price
    updateCartTotal(1, true);
    //show cart
    cartWrapper.removeClass('empty');
}
function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return val;
}
function addProduct(item, detail, product, pic, QTY) {



        //this is just a product placeholder
        //you should insert an item with the selected product info
        //replace productId, productName, price and url with your real product info
        productId = productId + 1;
        //var productAdded = $('<li class="product"><div class="product-image"><a href="#0"><img src="Cart/product-preview.png" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a href="#0">'+ product +'</a></h3><span class="price">$'+ 1 +'</span><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a><div class="quantity"><label for="cd-product-'+ productId +'">Qty</label><span class="select"><select id="cd-product-'+ productId +'" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option></select></span></div></div></div></li>');
        var productAdded = $('<li class="product"><div  class="product-image"><input type="text" name="item" value="' + item + '" hidden /><input type="text" name="detail" value="' + detail + '" hidden /><a href="#0"><img src="/view/images/' + pic + '" alt="placeholder"></a></div><div class="product-details"><h3><a  href="#0">' + product + '</a></h3><input type="text" name="productname" value="' + product + '" hidden /><input type="text" name="pic" value="/view/images/' + pic + '" hidden  /><span class="price">จำนวน</span><span class="price">' + QTY + ' kg.</span><input class="price" type="text" hidden name="QTY" value="' + QTY + '"><div class="actions"><a href="#0" class="delete-item">ลบ</a></div></div></li>');

    cartList.prepend(productAdded);
}
function removeProduct(product) {
    clearInterval(undoTimeoutId);
    cartList.find('.deleted').remove();

    var topPosition = product.offset().top - cartBody.children('ul').offset().top ,
        productQuantity = Number(product.find('.quantity').find('select').val()),
        productTotPrice = Number(product.find('.price').text().replace('$', '')) * productQuantity;

    product.css('top', topPosition+'px').addClass('deleted');

    //update items count + total price
    updateCartTotal(1, false);
    updateCartCount(true, -productQuantity);
    undo.addClass('visible');

    //wait 8sec before completely remove the item
    undoTimeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        undo.removeClass('visible');
        cartList.find('.deleted').remove();
    }, 0);
}

function quickUpdateCart() {
    var quantity = 0;
    var price = 0;

    cartList.children('li:not(.deleted)').each(function(){
        var singleQuantity = Number($(this).find('select').val());
        quantity = quantity + singleQuantity;
        price = price + singleQuantity*Number($(this).find('.price').text().replace('$', ''));
    });

    cartTotal.text(price.toFixed(2));
    cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(quantity);
    cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(quantity+1);
}

function updateCartCount(emptyCart, quantity) {
    if( typeof quantity === 'undefined' ) {
        var actual = Number(cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text()) + 1 ;
        var next = actual + 1;

        if( emptyCart ) {
            cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(actual);
            cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(next);
        } else {
            cartCount.addClass('update-count');

            setTimeout(function() {
                cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(actual);
            }, 150);

            setTimeout(function() {
                cartCount.removeClass('update-count');
            }, 200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(next);
            }, 230);
        }
    } else {
        var actual = Number(cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text()) -1 ;
        var next = actual + 1;

        cartCount.find('li').eq(0).text(actual);
        cartCount.find('li').eq(1).text(next);
    }
}

function updateCartTotal(price, bool) {
    bool ? cartTotal.text( (Number(cartTotal.text())  + Number(price)).toFixed(0) )  : cartTotal.text( (Number(cartTotal.text()) - Number(price)).toFixed(0) );
}
```

});

and when i change back to this page it stack a function (one time come back to this page it will do 2 time function and more if you come back again) I must to say sorry my English is not good and so thank you for help.

Comment: What does "non MVC RAZOR" mean? If your script is in "Index_cp.vbhtml", it will get loaded every time "#chicken_tab2" is clicked... you should read up about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in jQuery so that you can have a single script that acts on dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thank you so must i'll to read it right now.